# MongoDB updateMany filter array creates rather than updates (v4.4)

Tags: mongodb

When I use the following code, new documents are created rather than updated. Additionally, no "winner" key is created.

```
winners = [ {"ticket_number": 10}, {"ticket_number": 20} ]
db.tickets.updateMany(winners, {"$set": {"winner": true"})
```

But when I run the following *deleteMany* it deletes the documents as expected (removing "ticket_number" 10 and 20):

```
db.tickets.deleteMany(winners)
```

Why does deleteMany work as expected but updateMany doesn't (in my opinion) as they both have the same filter mechanism (I believe)?

Comment: why do you say UpdateMany doesn't work as expected?  Your example does not use `UpdateMany()`.  It calls `insertMany()`.  InsertMany will insert documents.

Comment: That was a typo! My bad

Comment: What client/version are you using where that deleteMany call works?  When I try with the mongo shell, I get the error `MongoError: BSON field 'delete.deletes.q' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'`

Comment: @mongoobs are you still facing the problem?